# Stop at the first occurence in Regex

Tags: regex

I have a text containing only one person details but a lot of different pets informations. I am looking for a way to select **only the person details** using Regex.

[Here is what I've tried](https://regex101.com/r/Lwdq7N/1)

TEXT :

```
# Person
---
Name: Nick King 
Age: 18
Speech: "Hello!! How are you? Me & you are different. I'm the #1"

# Pet = Dog
---
Name: Bill

# Pet = Cat
---
Name: Zacky
```

REGEX :

```
#\s*Person(\n|.)+(?=#\s*Pet)
```

Regex always goes and captures to till **the last pet** due to **anychar (.) tag** I've used.

**How can I stop at first pet?**

*Assuming that "Dog" won't always be the first Pet in the list.*

Comment: Could you add the desired result with your example?

Comment: I am unable to edit my Post. Stackoverflow is sending a **404** when I click on Edit. Any idea?

Comment: Here is what I'm expecting to have


```
# Person
---
Name: Nick King 
Age: 18
Speech: "Hello!! How are you? Me & you are different. I'm the #1"
```


But I'm getting

```
# Person
---
Name: Nick King 
Age: 18
Speech: "Hello!! How are you? Me & you are different. I'm the #1"


# Pet = Dog
---
Name: Bill
```

Comment: You need to make your regex lazy, [`#\s*Person(\n|.)+?(?=#\s*Pet)`](https://regex101.com/r/Lwdq7N/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex might not be the best solution to this sort of problem - there are YAML interpreters you could use.

If you're committed to using a regex, there is a simple solution: being ungreedy.

### Locally Ungreedy

In your original regex, you had:

```
#\s*Person(\n|.)+(?=#\s*Pet)
```

In this, `(\n|.)+` was matching *as many characters as possible* before conducting the  `Pet` lookahead.

If you introduce `?` after the `+` to make this group read `(\n|.)+`, you will get *as few characters as possible* before conducting the lookahead.

```
#\s*Person(\n|.)+?(?=#\s*Pet)
```

Regex101 describes `+?` as follows:

> `+?` *Quantifier* — Matches between *one and unlimited times*, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

### Globally Ungreedy

As well as operating a local *ungreedy* switch, you can globally set quantifiers to be *ungreedy* by using the **U** flag.

Note that this reverses greediness globally, so if you set the **U** flag as well as using `+?`, you will again be matching *as many times as possible*. Use one solution or the other.

Comment: Thank you @Robin, it works great. I did not know **+? Quantifier**. It just saves my life.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `(\n|.)+` which matches too much but is also very inefficient as it alternates between any character or a newline.

You could match `# Person` and repeat matching all the lines that do not start with `# Pet`

```
#\s*Person(?:\r?\n(?!#\s*Pet\b).*)*
```

- `#\s*Person` Match # Person
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!#\s*Pet\b).*` Match the whole line when not starting with `# Pet`
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FuyFiL/1)